# He asks if I would help. He asks if I will help

Tags: tense, will-would

> He asks if I would help.

> He asks if I will help.

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

My dictionary says 'would' is another version of expressing the reinforced willingness of someone's 'will'. For example, the dictionary provided this sentence: If you would understand a nation, you must know its language.

Comment: What's the context? Have you seen the first sentence somewhere? If you made it up, why do you think it might be natural English?

Comment: @gotube 'would' is another version of expressing the reinforced willingness of someone's 'will'. For example, If you would understand a nation, you must know its language.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it stands. Please [edit] it to indicate everything someone answering the question needs to know, including what you already know and what work you've done to try and answer it on your own.

Comment: "[If you would understand a nation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If+you+would+understand+a+nation%22&sxsrf=APwXEdfOI-J0IE3_lIrho9uclSBBSrxBag%3A1685386909443&ei=nfZ0ZK_VGpuF9u8P77S3qAc&ved=0ahUKEwjvl6_Am5v_AhWbgv0HHW_aDXUQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22If+you+would+understand+a+nation%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIECCMQJ0oECEEYAFAAWMgNYK4TaABwAXgAgAFoiAGEA5IBAzIuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), you must know its language." Look at the results, which are very few, they appear to be Japanese. No one *would* say this today. Please tell us how old your dictionary is, and where it was printed.

Comment: Sorry, the sources are Korean not Japanese.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No problem because the dictionaries both Korean or Japanese make may be or are down to standard.:D